# Убрать дубликаты из списка, проблема смешения типов данных

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, list, типы-данных

Решаю задачи на "Ok, Python!"
И застрял на следующем задании:

> Дан список `[1.0, 'ok', True, 'ok', 7, 1]`. Удалите из него
> повторяющиеся элементы (в списке не должно остаться дублей). Выведите
> измененный список на экран.
> Будьте внимательны! Значения `1.0`, `True` и `1` – это не дубли!

Всё никак не понимаю как его выполнить. У меня выходит либо `[1.0, 'ok', 7]`, либо просто набор из данных

---

Я использовал несколько методов:
**Первый:**

```
my_list = [1.0, 'ok', True, 'ok', 7, 1]
dublicate = list(dict.fromkeys(my_list))
```

**Второй:**

```
my_list = [1.0, 'ok', True, 'ok', 7, 1]
dublicate = set(my_list)
pustoi = []
for num in dublicate:
    for sec in my_list:
        if sec == num and type(sec) == type(num):
            break
        else:
            pustoi.append(sec)
```

**Третий:**

```
my_list = [1.0, 'ok', True, 'ok', 7, 1]
dublicate = set(my_list)
```

Comment: Ответил ниже Вам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
my_list = [1.0, 'ok', True, 'ok', 7, 1]

used = []
no_duplicates = []

for elem in my_list:
    if (elem, type(elem)) not in used:
        used.append((elem, type(elem)))
        no_duplicates.append(elem)
        
print(no_duplicates)
```

---

*Вывод:*

> ```
> [1.0, 'ok', True, 7, 1]
> ```

---

*Обяснение:*

В переменной `used` (*«использованные»*) будем сохранять **пары** `(элемент, тип_элемента)`, когда мы с элементом и его типом встретимся в списке `my_list` **впервые**.

В том же случае (и в никаком другом) такой элемент записываем в список `no_duplicates` (*«без дубликатов»*).

---

*Примечание:*

Все ваши решения сломались на том, что `dict.fromkeys()` и `set()` учитывают **только значения**, вне зависимости от их типов.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: @Dark_knight228, не стоит. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Из списка сделайте множество пар *значение/тип*, поместите его в множество, извлеките пары из множества, сохраните значения в новый список:

```
source = [1.0, 'ok', True, 'ok', 7, 1]
unique = [v for v, _ in set((v, type(v)) for v in source)]
print(unique)
```

Если код выше вам трудно читать, вот похожая идея в виде цикла. `pairs` - множество пар *значение/тип*, которые уже встречались раньше. Пара попадает в результат, только если это новая пара. Порядок значений исходного списка сохраняется:

```
source = [1.0, 'ok', True, 'ok', 7, 1]

pairs = set()  # (v, type(v))
unique = []
for v in source:
    pair = v, type(v)
    if pair not in pairs:
        pairs.add(pair)
        unique.append(v)

print(unique)
```